# Nil __block variable setting a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, warnings, block

To avoid retain cycles and the warnings "capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle" i have add for every object in my block something like this

```
MyViewController *__weak weakSelf= self;
NSMutableArray *__weak weakArray=AnArray;
UILabel *__weak weakLabel=ALabel;

///the block code with some examples
 up2.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *responseString) { 

       [weakSelf aMethodInTheController];
       [weakLabel setHidden:NO];
       [weakArray addObject:@"something"];

 };
```

With a weak reference the retain cycle warnings are disappeared,but there's a problem if i introduce inside the block a nnstring that must be setted

```
MyViewController *__weak weakSelf= self;
NSMutableArray *__weak weakArray=AnArray;
UILabel *__weak weakLabel=ALabel;

NSString *__weak weakString=AString;

///the block code with some examples
up2.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *responseString) { 

   [weakSelf aMethodInTheController];
   [weakLabel setHidden:NO];
   [weakArray addObject:@"something"];
   weakString=@"atext";

 };
```

In this way i receive the error "variable is not assignable (missing _*block type specifier)", so i have added "*_block"

```
MyViewController *__weak weakSelf= self;
NSMutableArray *__weak weakArray=AnArray;
UILabel *__weak weakLabel=ALabel;

NSString *__weak weakString=AString;
__block NSString *BlockString =  weakString;    

///the block code with some examples
up2.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *responseString) { 

[weakSelf aMethodInTheController];
[weakLabel setHidden:NO];
[weakArray addObject:@"something"];
 BlockString=@"atext";

 };
```

In this way all seems to work correctly,at least until i'm inside the block... My original Astring variable is defined in the .h of my viewController, i have to access to its value later and outside the block, but it's value is always nil. Assign @"atext" to BlockString do not set a value to my original Astring variable? How i can do to set the value of a variable setted in .h of my viewController without receive warnings and without exit from the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assign `@"atext"` to `BlockString` do not set a value to my original `Astring` variable?

No, it does not set `Astring`, and it shouldn't set it: when you do this

```
NSString *__weak weakString=AString;
```

you create a second reference (that happens to be `__weak`) to the object referenced by the `AString` variable (say, it's `@"some-text"`):

[image: Before]

When you set `weakString` inside the block to `@"atext"`, you re-point the reference to a different object, but the `@"some-text"` object remains referenced by the `AString` variable:

[image: After]

If you want to change `AString` variable, set it inside your block. If it is an ivar, use `weakSelf->AString`. If it is local, add `__block` to its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `aLabel` and `anArray` are ivars of the view controller, you really only worry about `weakSelf`, and then reference any ivars and properties from there. And since you're effectively dereferencing ivars, you'd then have a strong reference inside the block (because you can't dereference weak variable). So, assuming that `aLabel`, `anArray`, an `aString` are ivars:

```
MyViewController *__weak weakSelf = self;

///the block code with some examples
up2.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *responseString) { 

    MyViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf aMethodInTheController];
        [strongSelf->aLabel setHidden:NO];
        [strongSelf->anArray addObject:@"something"];
        strongSelf->aString = @"something else";
    }
};
```

Frankly, I'm not a fan of dereferencing ivars, and I'd rather use properties (for a number of reasons). But both work.

For example of this pattern, see the "Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles" section of the [Transitioning To ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4) (notably a bit later where it talks about "non-trivial cycles").